# Overlapping layout on Android Studio in buttons and text views

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio's design interface doesn't look right...

[image: design view]

This is what I get when running the app

[image: running view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is a Relative Layout problem. These posts on Stack Overflow might help.

- [Buttons in Android are overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253111/buttons-in-android-are-overlapping-need-a-fix)
- [Relative layout scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657687/relativelayout-scrollview)
- [How can I prevent views from overlapping in relative layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583550/how-can-i-prevent-views-from-overlapping-in-relative-layout)

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are not adding any constrains.
Make sure your are adding at least one constraint per axis.